# Most Pythonic/Django way to dynamically load client libraries at runtime

Tags: python, django, oop, design-patterns, django-rest-framework

I'm writing a Django application in which we will have multiple client libraries that make calls to third party APIs. We want to be able to determine which client library to load at runtime when calling different endpoints. I'm trying to determine the most Django/Pythonic way to do this

The current idea is to store class name in a model field, query the model in the View, and pass the class name to a service factory that instantiates the relevant service and makes the query. I've also considered writing a model method that uses reflection to query the class name

For example lets say we have a model called Exchange that has an id, a name, and stores the client name.

```
class Exchange(models.Model):
    exchange_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.exchange_name
```

Then in the View we might have something like:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from MyProject.trades.models import Exchange
from django.http import Http404
from MyProject.services import *


class GetLatestPrice(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            exchange = Exchange.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Exchange.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        exchange = self.get_objectt(pk)
        service = service_factory.get_service(exchange.client_name)
        latest_price = service.get_latest_price()
        serializer = PriceSerializer(latest_price)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This syntax may not be perfect but it hasn't been tested. But the idea is that maybe we have

```
ExchangeA - client1 
ExchangeB - client2
ExchangeC - client3
```

And for each client we have a service class that all inherit from the same Abstract Base. Each service has an override that are all the same. That way when you call /api/get_latest_price you pass the Exchange id as a query param and the code loads whatever service and client library is relevant. This would be so we could easily add new types to the system, have consistent and small Views, and decouple the business logic. Is this an acceptable, scalable pythonic method? Or is there a better solution for it? Essentially the problem is implementing Polymorphism in django and seperating the domain model from the data model. This has to be a solved problem so I'm curious on the way other people might be doing this. I know it's unusual to be calling a third party API like this but since we are forced to I want to do it in the cleanest most scalable way possible.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but __don't use wildcard import__ (=> 'from MyProject.services import *') - they make the code unmaintainable and quite prone to breakage / totally unexpected behaviour. Always explicitely speficy names you want to import, or only import the module itself then use qualified names.

Comment: hahah yeah this was just for this example. I legit typed this code into StackOverflow body form. I NEVER do that haha. Thanks for the heads up though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

There's no silver bullet.

More useful answer:

There's no universal and convenient approach to solve your problem. solution may vary greatly depending on the implementation of client libraries and third party APIs. If they all are similar, you can use your approach and you'll be fine. If APIs have some differences, for instance, one API don't have endpoint to get latest price, you'll need to find some workarounds. If API's have some big differences in workflow you will need to find completely different approach, for instance, if one API can return a report right away, and some other will return report via callback after 5 minutes, you'll need to find workaround for this.

So the one real advise i can give you is to examine differences between third party APIs and focus more on the design of the highest abstractions of your own project, that will use low level client libraries. Try to minimize the impact of differences between third parties on your project.

Comment: I think the OP is already aware of this and was mostly asking about the validity of his general design (storing the service class name in the model and retrieving the service class from it's name) - but it's still worth mentionning that seemingly similar APIs can still impose widly different workflows, which can make the abstraction a bit leaky...

Comment: I would say, that `Exchange` is redundant in this case. They can have just simple confing in the code for that purpose. Model records can be useful if there will be some configuration, that can be changed, for example requests per second limit for API or enable/disable switch for each third party API. Just for storing list of available clients you can use a `dict` in your `settings.py`, environment variables or some other place, since adding support for new client will require adding integration code, like new service, and redeploying app anyway

Comment: Good point. I have to say I assumed the `Exchange` model had other responsabilitie the OP didn't mention cause they were irrelevant to the question - but if there's nothing else in the model then it's indeed kind of useless.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is essentially the answer I was hoping for but needed confirmation. And just to clarify I did leave out a lot of other code for the sake of brevity. Exchange does have a few other responsibilities and is also a foreign key in a many-to-many relationship to another table

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar situation here (and some other that are closely related), and use exactly this pattern: storing the name of the "service" class in the model and using some registry (your "service_factory") to get the class. It JustWorks(tm), no one (from the various devs that joined - and eventually left) ever complained about this design nor suggested any better solution, and the only small complication we've had so far is handling "discontinued" services that are still referenced from the database (and this really was no rocket science either).

FWIW, this is mostly a variant on the "strategy" design pattern, and I really fail to imagine a better (for "better" = "simpler, more effective and easier to maintain") solution for this need.

**EDIT**

Note that my above answer assumes that `Exchange` has other responsabilites not mentionned in your question - else, as Alexandr Zayets states, this model seems rather useless ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It was extremely difficult to pick the correct answer as you both provided valuable insight. I chose the other one simply because it provided just a bit more in the inverse but I upvoted your answer